# Highcharts - update chart using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Here is my sample chart with random data
http://jsfiddle.net/Fw4PZ/

```
$(function () {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: false
            }
        });

        var chart;
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'container',
                type: 'area',
                marginRight: 10,
                events: {
                    load: function() {

                        // set up the updating of the chart each second
                        var series = this.series[1];
                        setInterval(function() {
                            var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                                y = Math.random();
                            series.addPoint([x, y], true);
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Live random data'
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'datetime',
                tickPixelInterval: 150
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: 'Value'
                },
                plotLines: [{
                    value: 0,
                    width: 1,
                    color: '#808080'
                }]
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                        Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) +'<br/>'+
                        Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
                }
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            exporting: {
                enabled: false
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Random data',
                data: []
            },{
                name: 'Random data',
                type: 'spline',
                data: []
            }]
        });
    });

});
```

How to update each series, not only [1] ?

```
                load: function() {

                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series[0];
                    setInterval(function() {
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                            y = Math.random();
                        series.addPoint([x, y], true);
                    }, 1000);

                    // set up the updating of the chart each second
                    var series = this.series[1];
                    setInterval(function() {
                        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                            y = Math.random();
                        series.addPoint([x, y], true);
                    }, 1000);
                }
```

Doesn't work...

And 2nd thing... how to update those series using ajax? (I need to have 2 areas and 4 splines)

**UPDATE**
So i change this

```
        events: {
            load: function() {

                // set up the updating of the chart each second
                var series = this.series;
                setInterval(function() {
                    var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
                        y = Math.random();

                    series[0].addPoint([x, y], false);
                    series[1].addPoint([x, y], false);
                    series[2].addPoint([x, y], false);
                    series[3].addPoint([x, y], false);
                    series[4].addPoint([x, y], false);
                    series[5].addPoint([x, y], true);
                }, 5000);
            }
        }
```

but it crashes my browser :\
http://jsfiddle.net/2tmRB/1/ (watch out with that link!)
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: But I cannot open this example because all is frozen. Take look at example: http://jsfiddle.net/Fw4PZ/3/ which works properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example:

```
var series = this.series;
setInterval(function() {
  var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
  y = Math.random(), 
  y1 = Math.random();
  series[0].addPoint([x, y], false);
  series[1].addPoint([x, y1], true);
}, 1000);
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/Fw4PZ/1/

Regarding AJAX - just in setInterval call some getJSON() or something similar, and add values from that response to the chart using `addPoint()` (like in above example).

Comment: I have problem with more series :( It crashes my browser (see topic)

Comment: You are mixing categorized axis(`categories: [...]`) with datetime axis ([timestamp, value]) so it's trying to display categories for all timestamps until 1369142816260 (example), so it hangs browser. Use or categories, or datetime xAxis: http://jsfiddle.net/Zf26V/2/

Comment: I have something similar to this - but am noticing with each iteration of setInterval my browser seems to get bogged down more. I'm using update - is that a Highcharts thing?

Comment: Create jsFiddle example with that issue, please.